# Proof of an inequality about sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Let $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ are real number sequences.
> Proof of this inequality
> $$
> \sqrt{
> \sum_{n=1}^{k} (x_n-y_n)^2}
> \leq 
> \sqrt{
> \sum_{n=1}^{k} x_n^2}
> +
> \sqrt{
> \sum_{n=1}^{k} y_n^2}$$

My mathematics book says that we can prove this inequality by using Cauchy–Schwarz inequality, but I don't know how I have to use Cauchy–Schwarz inequality.

Does anyone know how to use Cauchy–Schwarz inequality in this situation?

Comment: This inequality can be expressed interestingly by vector-geometry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By C-S
$$\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^kx_n^2}+\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^ky_n^2}=\sqrt{\left(\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^kx_n^2}+\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^ky_n^2}\right)^2}=$$
$$=\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}(x_n^2+y_n^2)+2\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^kx_n^2\sum_{n=1}^ky_n^2}}\geq\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^k(x_n^2+y_n^2)+2\sqrt{\left(\sum_{n=1}^kx_ny_n\right)^2}}=$$
$$=\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^k(x_n^2+y_n^2)+2\left|\sum_{n=1}^kx_ny_n\right|}\geq\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^k(x_n^2+y_n^2)-2\sum_{n=1}^kx_ny_n}=\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^k(x_n-y_n)^2}.$$
Also, we can use Minkowski here:
$$\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^kx_n^2}+\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^ky_n^2}=\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^kx_n^2}+\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^k(-y_n)^2}\geq\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^k(x_n-y_n)^2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Just notice that the left hand side is $||x-y||$ where $x=(x_1,\cdots,x_k)$ and $y=(y_1,\cdots,y_k)$ are vectors on $\mathbb{R}^n$, with usual Euclidean norm. Then by the triangle inequality $$||x-y||\leq||x||+||y||$$ which is the result you want.

Comment: Do we not need to prove what the post is asking in order to confirm that the Euclidean norm is a norm, in particular that it satisfies the triangle inequality?

Comment: @AndréArmatowski Yes, actually that may be the objective of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try squaring both sides and try to simplify the result. You should be able to simplify the equation to

$$ \sum x_i y_i \leq ( \sum x_i^2 ) ( \sum y_i^2 ). $$

But this IS exactly the Cauchy Schwartz inequality.