# Prove that $\sqrt{(x-2)^2+y^2}+\sqrt{(x-4)^2+(y-2)^2}+\sqrt{(x-2)^2+(y-5)^2}+\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2}\geq8$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Prove that $\sqrt{(x-2)^2+y^2}+\sqrt{(x-4)^2+(y-2)^2}+\sqrt{(x-2)^2+(y-5)^2}+\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2}\geq8$ for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. I used this [Proof of an inequality about sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3827944/proof-of-an-inequality-about-sequences) to solve it and it worked, but I have no ideea how to interpret it geometrically. Any help, please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please develope it a little, I am working simultaneously at this and another problem and I am not quite good at geometry unfortunatelly. In case of a beautiful answer I accept it and upvote it. Later edit: The one who wrote a comment deleted it :((((. I hope it's still around and has not abandoned this thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's $A(2,0), B(4,2),C(2,5), D(1,2)$ and $G(x,y)$ on the plane $Oxy$. The left hand side of the inequality is the sum  $$\mathbf{S} =GA+GB+GC+GD$$

The inequality becomes: find $G$ such that the sum $\mathbf{S}$ is minimized.
We have
$$GA+GC \ge AC$$  $$GB+GD \ge BD$$
then $$S = GA+GB+GC+GD \ge AC+BD = \sqrt{2^2+5^2}+3 = \sqrt{29}+3$$

The sum is then minimized if $G$ is at $I$, the intersection of two lines: $AC$ and $BD$.

Comment: Hm, I don`t know who downvoted you but, indeed, there should be a little more developement since the inequality works for every $x,y$ real and I don't think we can reduce the inequality so fast to a fixed point or to say ,,find $G$ such that". The conclusion should be changed or the interpretation in some respect.

Comment: @AnatolDenicula: The problem is now proved geometrically.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thank you very much, it is a beautiful interpretation!

Comment: @AnatolDenicula You're welcome.

Comment: What do you say about this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4083054/properties-of-x-0-2003-x-n1-fx-n-n-geq1?noredirect=1#comment8436956_4083054?